Camera stopped working on Dell XPS 9320 after upgrade
The internal webcam on my Dell XSP 9320 stopped working. I suspect it was caused by the following upgrade, especially given that the linux-modules-ipu6-oem package was removed.
Start-Date: 2024-10-05  10:12:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.3506'
Upgrade: google-chrome-stable:amd64 (129.0.6668.70-1, 129.0.6668.89-1), libmutter-10-0:amd64 (42.9-0ubuntu8, 42.9-0ubuntu9), oem-somerville-factory-tentacool-rpl-meta:amd64 (22.04ubuntu6, 22.04ubuntu8), mutter-common:amd64 (42.9-0ubuntu8, 42.9-0ubuntu9), gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 (42.9-0ubuntu8, 42.9-0ubuntu9), linux-firmware:amd64 (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31, 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.34), oem-somerville-tentacool-rpl-meta:amd64 (22.04ubuntu6, 22.04ubuntu8), xdg-desktop-portal:amd64 (1.14.4-1ubuntu2~22.04.1, 1.14.4-1ubuntu2~22.04.2)
Remove: linux-modules-6.1.0-1036-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1036.36), linux-headers-6.0.0-1011-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1011.11), linux-modules-ipu6-oem-22.04b:amd64 (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1), linux-oem-6.0-headers-6.0.0-1011:amd64 (6.0.0-1011.11), linux-headers-6.1.0-1036-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1036.36), linux-image-6.0.0-1011-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1011.11), linux-oem-6.1-headers-6.1.0-1036:amd64 (6.1.0-1036.36), linux-image-6.1.0-1036-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1036.36), linux-modules-6.0.0-1011-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1011.11), linux-modules-ivsc-oem-22.04b:amd64 (6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-10-05  10:13:30

Start-Date: 2024-10-05  14:08:06
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: yashabk (1001)
Remove: libia-cmc-parser-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-mkn0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-aiqb-parser-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-mkn-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-ccat0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-ccat-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-lard0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-cca-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-nvm-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-cca0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libcamhal0:amd64 (0~git202406210224.cb00bdd~ubuntu22.04.1), libbroxton-ia-pal-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-emd-decoder0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-isp-bxt0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-cmc-parser-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-log-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-bcomp0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-exc-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-nvm0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libbroxton-ia-pal0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-dvs-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-nvm-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-ltm-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-log-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), gstreamer1.0-icamera:amd64 (0~git202404150111.3d9cd3a~ubuntu22.04.3), libia-aiq-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-dvs0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libgsticamerainterface-1.0-1:amd64 (0~git202404150111.3d9cd3a~ubuntu22.04.3), libia-emd-decoder-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-aiq-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-aiqb-parser-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-ltm-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libgcss-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-exc-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-isp-bxt-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-exc0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-coordinate-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-cca-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-isp-bxt-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-aiqb-parser0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libcamhal-common:amd64 (0~git202406210224.cb00bdd~ubuntu22.04.1), v4l2-relayd:amd64 (0.1.2-0ubuntu1), libia-ccat-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-lard-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-bcomp-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-dvs-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-aiq0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libcamhal-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202406210224.cb00bdd~ubuntu22.04.1), libgcss0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-log0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-emd-decoder-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-lard-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-coordinate-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-ltm0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-bcomp-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-coordinate0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libgcss-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libbroxton-ia-pal-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-mkn-ipu6ep0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1), libia-cmc-parser0:amd64 (0~git202310270317.0dad591-1~ubuntu22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-10-05  14:08:17

The laptop came with Ubuntu factory installed. Is there a way to troubleshoot the issue or to revert the upgrade?

I tried these commands on my computer and the problem was fixed.
kill the snapshot proccess with terminal. Sometimes, the snapshot process might be causing the issue. You can find the process by typing this command to terminal:
ps -ef | grep snapshot

Look for the process with the command "/usr/bin/snapshot" use the PID to kill the snapshot process with command bellow:
kill -9 <snapshot PID>

now try to update your system and restart the pipewire service:
sudo apt update 
systemctl --user restart pipewire

for me to test if the camera works, i installed the following software which called cheese.
sudo apt install cheese

I hope this is gonna fix your issue
